# How to do a surface with pstricks using data from a surveying?

Tags: pstricks, 3d

For each point of the grid a have the coordinates (X,Y) and height (Z), like:

```
X
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3

Y
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

Z
2 1 0
4 5 1
8 4 3
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution with [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots):

```
\documentclass[png,tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
X Y Z
1 1 2
2 1 1
3 1 0

1 2 4
2 2 5
3 2 1

1 3 8
2 3 4
3 3 3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[surf] file[skip first] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Claudio. With tikz I already have done. But I would like pstricks because I have others elements, that are in pstricks, to compose all the picture.